# UDP packet on 2 thread with same port

Tags: c, linux, udp

Due design constraint I have to open 2 thread for `recvfrom(UDP packet)`, for two different operations which are running parallel.

1. Data received on an unexpected thread which leads to not receiving data and both thread timeout after a time expiry.
2. I tried `MSG_PEEK` and then communication bet. threads using a signal which I dropped later on.

Is there any approach I can follow here?

Comment: I'm guessing that the two message streams come from two different peers, or two different ports on the same peer, yes?

Comment: Use a third thread to do the receiving and despatch to whichever of the original two threads is appropriate. Or revise your 'design constraint'. Design constraints should not specify a threading model.

Comment: @MartinJames thanks , No see the msg expected on thread1 received on thread2 that means its coming from same peer. Now the as soon as we read using recvfrom we erase data from buffer and so sender wont be able to send it again and that will lead here packet drop for expected receiving thread.

Comment: @manohar In response to your now-deleted comment ' is there any other approach other then having a third thread ...': yes, there is, and I have already stated it.

Comment: Thanks @EJP i will look into that one. Comment were deleted from this thread was unexpected to me too. anyway thanks for your suggestion looking in that direction too.